# combine data according to some values in matlab

Tags: matlab

I encountered a problem related to combining data in Matlab according to some values and any help would be appreciated.

Suppose there is a vector t that records time points between 0 and 10 (not evenly spaced) and a vector vals that records values of some outputs at the corresponding time points. So vals is of same length as t.

```
t = [0 0.02 0.18 0.21 0.4 0.4 ... 9.03];
vals = [1.1 0 5.9 2.7 6 1.2... 15.3];
```

The underline process is periodic of period 2 and I would like to look at the outputs in one period. So I calculated tp to get the distribution of those time points in one period.

```
tp  = sort(unique(mod(t,2)/2));
```

Next step is to calculate a vector vals_pd of accumulated values in one period. For example in the vector vals, both 6 and 1.2 correspond to time point 0.4 in the vector t. 0.4 corresponds to 0.2 in tp. Then in the vector vals_pd, I want 6+1.2 be at the same position as 0.2 in tp.

I don't know if there is a good way of calculating the vector vals_pd. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example for `t` and `vals`? Also, you say, that the values in `t` range from 0 to 10. Doesn't that mean, that the periodic process also takes place in that range!?